# How can identityserver4 access external web api secured by the identityserver4 issuer

Tags: identityserver4

I have a web api that is secured by identityserver4. I need to access this web api from identityserver4 using client_credentials grant type.

How can identityserver4 generate a token internally to make a call to a web api secured by the same identityserver4 issuer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via the `IdentityServerTools` helper - this is documented here:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/tools.html